# it is possible do this on PostGIS?

Tags: postgis

it is possible do this on PostGIS?

[image]

WKT from this geom:

```
'LineString (-103.38799494051174577 21.84240787106980974, -103.18255979902365027 21.95852338582395546, -102.94586278817865832 21.96298936716065242, -103.07537624694289491 22.03891104988451843, -103.04858035892270607 22.07687189124645144, -103.07314325627454821 22.13269665795517582, -102.97489166686719386 22.20861834067903828, -102.83198026409286285 22.27560806072951038, -102.73596166535385521 22.28900600473960125, -102.67790390797678413 22.29347198607630176, -102.60644820658961862 22.2845400234029043, -102.57518633723272217 22.24657918204097129, -102.57518633723272217 22.19075441533224691, -102.60421521592125771 22.13269665795517582, -102.69800082399191865 22.05900796589966006, -102.81188334807771412 22.0165811432010301, -102.8699411054547852 21.98755226451249101, -102.90566895614837506 21.96466411016191245, -102.78676220305879951 21.96801359616443605, -102.52550229486199385 21.95684864282269899, -102.27317434933856077 21.88092696009883298)'
```

Comment: Your question title and body ask two different questions. And the body asks two questions , which violates the One question per Question policy emphasized by the [Tour]. Please choose a software package you want to use to perform a buffer, the edit the question to focus on the exact tool you have used and what attempt you have made to resolve the issue.

Comment: oK, thanks for your feedback I changed the question, do yo have any idea how to do that?

Comment: I'd read the layer into QGIS and modify it by hand

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain what exactly you are wanting to do, and what you've tried.  An "is it possible" question can usually just be answered with a "yes" or a "no", but really that probably doesn't help you at all.  Tell us what you're trying to do and where you're stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like [ST_ChaikinSmoothing](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ChaikinSmoothing.html) might work if you just want to smooth it out a little. Note the amount is controlled by the `niterations` argument (see docs) and 5 is the max which is used in the statement below.

Using your line:

```
select ST_AsText(ST_ChaikinSmoothing('LineString (-103.38799494051174577 21.84240787106980974, -103.18255979902365027 21.95852338582395546, -102.94586278817865832 21.96298936716065242, -103.07537624694289491 22.03891104988451843, -103.04858035892270607 22.07687189124645144, -103.07314325627454821 22.13269665795517582, -102.97489166686719386 22.20861834067903828, -102.83198026409286285 22.27560806072951038, -102.73596166535385521 22.28900600473960125, -102.67790390797678413 22.29347198607630176, -102.60644820658961862 22.2845400234029043, -102.57518633723272217 22.24657918204097129, -102.57518633723272217 22.19075441533224691, -102.60421521592125771 22.13269665795517582, -102.69800082399191865 22.05900796589966006, -102.81188334807771412 22.0165811432010301, -102.8699411054547852 21.98755226451249101, -102.90566895614837506 21.96466411016191245, -102.78676220305879951 21.96801359616443605, -102.52550229486199385 21.95684864282269899, -102.27317434933856077 21.88092696009883298)', 5));
```

The result is below (plotted in python):
[image]

Comment: Thanks, also work ST_OffsetCurve but the geom is elevate